# Umbraco manual installation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco

I downloaded Umbraco 7.7.2, unzipped folder and opened in VS2015 as website. When i compile or run project i get error

> The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Projects\CMS\UmbracoCms.7.7.2\Umbraco\PartialViewMacros\Templates\Gallery.cshtml

This is code that is throwing error
[image: Image of Source Code]

Comment: I guess it's something related to the models builder, try changing the value in the web.config to <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="PureLive" />

Comment: I confirmed from web.config, ModelsBuilder is already enabled and mode set to PureLive

Comment: Take a look here: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/getting-started-with-modelsbuilder/ at the paragraph "Dll Models". Have a try with that

Comment: Why not to install Umbraco from NuGet? It should do all the required configuration changes for you and it works :)

Comment: Thanks @MarcinZajkowski , Installation by NuGet worked for me :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Enjoy the rest! :)